# Como guardar un arreglo bidimensional guardado en un archivo a una variable en lenguaje c

Tags: c, archivo, matrices

Bueno basicamente lo que quiero hacer es guardar en una variable la matriz que se ubica en un archivo ya antes guardado, para asi despues poder modificar los valores de la matriz y guardarlo en otro archivo, pero al momento en que intento imprimir la matriz (Se supone ya guardada dentro de una variable), me imprime valores los cuales no son de la matriz que estaban guardados, el codigo que uso es el siguiente:

```
int main()
{

    int a[5][10] = { (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) };
    int aux, i, j;
    FILE* arreglo = fopen("Consultorios.txt", "r");
    if (arreglo == NULL) {
        printf("No se puede abrir el archivo");
    }
    while (aux != EOF) {
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
                aux = fgetc(arreglo);

                if (aux == EOF) {
                    break;
                }

                a[i][j] = aux;
                printf("%c", a[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    fflush(arreglo);
    fclose(arreglo);

    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("\n");
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            printf("|%d|", a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**

```
|0| |0| |0| |0| |102| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| 
|0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| 
|0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| 
|0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| 
|0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0| |0|
```

** Lo que esta dentro del archivo
*

Comment: ¿Dónde está declarada `a`?

Comment: La declare dentro del int main, osea dentro del mismo programa

Comment: ¿Y no puedes mostrar todo `main`? Al menos la parte en que se declara `a`, para ver cómo se declara e inicializa.

Comment: Ya añadi el main, solamente iniacialice toda la matriz en ceros y declare el aux, i y j

Comment: Perdona por no haberlo pedido todo a la vez ¿puedes poner un ejemplo de tu archivo de datos?

Comment: Ya agregue el archivo

Comment: Las imágenes tienen dos problemas: Su contenido no puede copiarse y, si dejan de estar disponibles en el futuro, la pregunta carecerá de sentido. Por favor, pon el contenido del archivo... no una imagen.

Comment: Entiendo, ya coloque su contenido.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás leyendo caracter a caracter, lo que quieres es leer número a número:

```
FILE *f = fopen("f", "r");
if (f)
{
    printf("Leyendo archivo.\n");
    int numero;

    while (fscanf(f, "|%d| ", &numero) != EOF)
    {
        printf("%d ", numero);
    }
}
fclose(f);
```

Echa un vistazo al [código de ejemplo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/SBvBaBwbQqD0oEh3).

Comment: Ya vi el codigo de ejemplo, y me imprime todo, pero ya con ese codigo ¿puedo cambiar valores a lo que ya me guardo e imprimio dentro del codigo?

Comment: Cuando lees en `numero`, puedes guardar lo leído en `a` y hacer con ello lo que necesites.

Comment: Ohh Ya, Muchas Gracias, Me sirvio